# SHA512, SHA256, any hash in general is deprecated?

Tags: macos, sha

Why are the hashes deprecated for Mac OSX 10.7 and higher?

Comment: You're gonna need some context here.

Comment: in general the hash functions are depreciated, sorry for being vague

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CommonCrypto framework isn't deprecated, and provides all the hashes that you need. See the manpage for `CC_SHA`.